# Why does my await function complete immediately?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i was hoping somebody could help me understand where i am going wrong, i have a basic bit of JavaScript; when a user clicks a button the inner HTML of a div is replaced to  loading Gif while the rest of the functions calculate a final value and then the loading gif should be replaced with the final value. However what actually happens is the entire process is completed before any changes are made, so the loading gif is set and replaced with the final value instantly at the end. It works fine in firefox but not in chrome or IE. I need the loading giff to be set immediately so the user can see the value is being calculated as it can take some time.

```
const loadingGif = "path to giff";

$('#btn1').click(function() { 
        buttonClick()
});


function buttonClick(){
    setLoadingGiff("buttonValue")
};

async function setLoadingGiff(range){
$('#divID').html(loadingGif);
var result = await calcFunction(range);
}

function calcFunction(){

//Do calculations ....
//finally
const finalCalulcation = "value";
$('#divID').html(finalCalulcation);

}
```

Comment: Your JS execution probably blocks the UI from updating. The usual way is to break it up by putting your code in a `setTimeout`. You can safely specify a timeout amount of `0`, which will schedule the code to be executed as soon as possible but the browser does have the option to catch up and update the page before continuing with the logic.

Comment: What happens if you move the `$('#divID').html(loadingGif)` line into `buttonClick()` or even `$('#btn1').click(...)` ?

Comment: 1.  Are there any promises or observables in calcFunction?  If not then I don't think async/await is going to do anything.  If it is returning a promise then try adding a setTimeout() to give the browser a chance to redraw the screen.

Comment: What exactly is `calcFunction` doing? If it is synchronous, then there's no reason to use an `async function`

Comment: I have tried to add the function call to the button click but it makes no difference. When i wrap the loadinggif function in a timeout it allows the rest of the code to run and then sets the giff which overwrites the calculated value.

Comment: calcfunction is doing a lot which i cannot post on here, mainly calls to data sets then calculating based on the returned values. I haven't used any promises within calcFunction but there are async ajax calls. everything within that function runs in order and updates as it it being ran.

Comment: If it is somthing in calcfunction is there a way to say do setLoadingGiff() fully then move onto calcFunction()? i tried to do this in a promise but it made no difference